# Regex cond should only enter at 'abc else' and not 'abc else if'

Tags: regex

This is my condition:

```
  if( /else$/.test(kword_search) && !/else\s+if$/.test(kword_search)  )
```

It becomes true even if kword_search's value is 'abc else if' where in it should not

Comment: What's the purpose of the `[^if]` part supposed to be? Can you walk through exactly what your string should look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
/[\S\s]*[^if]\s*else(?!\s?if)$/.test(kword_search)
```

This looks ahead and ensures the abc is not followed by if.

Comment: it still accept this particular string "void main(){

    if ( sf=sf) {
    }
    
    else if"

Comment: Can you clarify on what you actually want? Do you just want fo find occurrences of else not followed by if? if that is all it will just be the regex:
    else(?!\s?if)

Comment: pass occurence of 'abc if(d){} else' but not 'abc if(d){} else if'

Comment: i should not reject all ifs before the else, because this will work like a syntax checker. when it sees 'if$' it will enter a condition same as when it sees 'else if' and 'else'

Comment: His tests seem to work as you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/B9w6H/ Open the console, see it yields `true` for the first test but `false` for the second.